# Mixing high-order functions and Result

Tags: rust

I'm not really sure how to write a high-order function that wants to return an error of its own and make it look nice when I use it on another functions that also return a `Result`.

This is hard to describe. Here's an example:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError;
impl Error for MyError {}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "MyError")
    }
}

fn log_something() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn log_and_call<T>(f: &dyn Fn() -> T) -> Result<T, MyError> {
    log_something()?;
    Ok(f())
}

fn the_answer() -> i32 {
    42
}

fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut f = fs::File::open("hello.txt")?;
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
    Ok(s)
}


fn main() {
    let _logged_answer: Result<i32, MyError> = log_and_call(&the_answer);
    let _logged_username: Result<Result<String, io::Error>, MyError> = log_and_call(&read_username_from_file);
}
```

How do I avoid having that `Result<Result<String, io::Error>, MyError>` there? I'd like to have `Result<String, Error>`, or maybe something even more sensible.

Maybe there's a more idomatic way to do this?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with making a `flatten_result` function that converts `Result<Result<T, E1>, E2>` into `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>` then just calling it like `flatten_result(log_and_call(...))`?

Comment: That puts a burden on specific users of `log_and_call`, which feels undue. If there was a way to specialise it for `Result`-returning `f`s, that'd work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the help of traits:

```rust
fn log_and_call<T: ToResult>(f: &dyn Fn() -> T) -> Result<T::Value, MyError> {
    log_something()?;
    f().to_result()
}

fn the_answer() -> i32 {
    42
}

trait ToResult {
    type Value;

    fn to_result(self) -> Result<Self::Value, MyError>;
}

impl<T, E: Error> ToResult for Result<T, E> {
    type Value = T;
    fn to_result(self) -> Result<Self::Value, MyError> {
        self.map_err(|err| MyError::from(err))
    }
}

impl ToResult for i32 {
    type Value = i32;
    fn to_result(self) -> Result<Self::Value, MyError> {
        Ok(self)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let _logged_answer: Result<i32, MyError> = log_and_call(&the_answer);
    let _logged_username: Result<String, MyError> = log_and_call(&read_username_from_file);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be76642ec28179a9d9f22a1d681b7486)

---

I don't exactly know your use case, so if you just want to grab the value inside the result wherever you are calling, `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` can be used at return position:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let _logged_answer: i32 = log_and_call(&the_answer)?;
    let _logged_username: String = log_and_call(&read_username_from_file)??;
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8621c6e7de5127acb59c48517b94ad07)

---

Another way could be to change `log_and_call` to this:

```rust
fn log_and_call<T, E: Error>(f: &dyn Fn() -> Result<T, E>) -> Result<T, MyError> where MyError: From<E> {
    log_something()?;
    Ok(f()?)
}
```

and then calling the function like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let _logged_answer: Result<i32, MyError> = log_and_call(&||-> Result<_, MyError> {Ok(the_answer())});
    let _logged_username: Result<String, MyError> = log_and_call(&read_username_from_file);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15f046101bad293ed587b5aa25dd30ce)

You could define a macro or a function to do this wrapping in a closure returning `Result`:

```rust
macro_rules! wrap {
    ($($content:tt)+) => {
        ||-> Result<_, MyError> {Ok($($content)+)}
    };
}

fn main() {
    let _logged_answer: Result<i32, MyError> = log_and_call(&wrap!(the_answer()));
    let _logged_username: Result<String, MyError> = log_and_call(&read_username_from_file);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc177485da1c1ba2130ee98137036e3e)

---

Another solution could be to have something like `flatten_result` as suggested by Aplet in question comments.

Comment: +1 for the `Into<MyError>` solution. The built-in `?` operator uses `Into<MyError>` internally, and it's great for navigating complex error hierarchies.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that makes sense, didn't notice it before. Refactored the function.

Comment: @MihirLuthra Great answer!  Is there perhaps a way to provide a default implementation? Feels like we're burdening every user of `log_and_call` to `impl` for every new type. Not quite sure how to get out of this hole. Maybe requiring `T` to be sized wouldn't be too bad?

Comment: @pkoch I think that would require [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) which is still not stabilized. In such cases, you can generally impl traits for all basic types like `i32`, `bool`, `String`, etc. by a simple `macro_rules!` macro and have a simple `derive` macro from custom types. I personally can't think of a better way. Also, the above answer is just a basic idea. If you think adding `Sized` suits your needs, then yes.